# EEPROM page size

Tags: stm32, eeprom

I have an [M24C01-x](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00001163.pdf) EEPROM (1 KBit in size) driven by an STM32. The datasheet doesn't make it clear what the page size of that EEPROM is. I require it to properly configure the STM32 EEPROM driver.

How can I calculate/know the page size of the M24C01-x?

Comment: Isn't it mentioned on page 14? The page size is 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page size is 16 bytes, as stated in the datasheet.

> The Page Write mode allows up to 16 bytes to be written in a single Write cycle, provided 
>   that they are all located in the same page in the memory: that is, the most significant 
>   memory address bits are the same. If more bytes are sent than will fit up to the end of the 
>   page, a condition known as ‘roll-over’ occurs. This should be avoided, as data starts to 
>   become overwritten in an implementation dependent way.

Page 14.

So your 1KBit memory has 8 pages, each 16 bytes in size.

Answer (score 4):

Page 14 of the datasheet:

> The Page Write mode allows up to 16 bytes to be written in a single Write cycle

So a page appears to be 16 bytes.